# Как сбросить кэш страницы через Javascript?

Tags: html, ajax, веб-программирование, вёрстка, кэширование

Есть страница сайта, на ней данные подгружаются динамически через AJAX. Как сделать, чтобы при переходе по истории (кнопки браузера "Вперед"/"Назад") в кэше сохранялась наиболее свежая версия страницы (сейчас сохраняется версия при первоначальной загрузке страницы).

Задача в том, чтобы не запрещать все кэширование через header'ы или на уровне сервера, а провести разовый сброс кэша через Javascript при поступлении новых данных.

Comment: Я думаю, что тут нужно ставить или таймер или доп-скрипт, который вычислит что страница доисторическая, и обновит её ajax-подзапросом + document.write. Как вариант2, есть параметр "время жизни" контента, указав там конкретное время (текущее + минута) браузер будет знать что время "истекло" и перезагрузит страницу, но для post-запроса большими буквами скажет что "страница устарела" .

Comment: @nick_n_a нет, отдельного таймера здесь не нужно, т.к. заранее известно событие, при котором происходит перестройка DOM-дерева. вопрос в том, как после такой перестройки незаметно для пользователя (т.е. без видимых обновлений страницы и т.д.) дать команду браузеру, что версия страницы в кэше устарела и требуется загрузить ее новую версию.

Comment: Повторюсь, загрузить подзапросом XmlHttpRequest или чо-то в этом роде и сделать document.write("Новый контент"). Второе - насильно сказать location.href="адрес контента" но тогда "попортится" история и будут глюки при кнопке назад.